# X Mirror and copying weight paints

Tags: weight-painting, mirror

I'm a bit confused with the X Mirror option and how you're supposed to copy weight paints from one side to the other. Is X Mirror supposed to work by painting the opposite side automatically as you paint the other? Or am I misunderstanding how it works. Either way, it doesn't appear to do much for me. Failing that, how am I supposed to copy my weight paints from one side to the other?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

x-mirror in weight paint mode is meant to mirror your actions between mirrored groups.

Let's say you have group four your right and left arm. If you paint the weights in the left arm group, x mirror will do its job on the right arm group.

In order to paint in symmetry inside a single group, you need the purposely named symmetry tool :
[image: demo pic]

Comment: Oh, I'm so confused... I have Vertex Groups for my two shoulders, the (character's) left shoulder has had its weight paint adjusted, the X Mirror is enabled, but it doesn't replicate it on the right shoulder. Also, I'm not getting an option for Symmetry.

Comment: Are you in weight paint mode?

Comment: Yeah, I am. ...

Comment: provide your .blend file then.

Comment: Uploaded it to the original post. I asked the same question before and someone tried it and it worked for them, so whether I'm just completely misunderstanding how it works, I don't know...
At the moment I'm trying to copy the currently selected weight paint to the opposite shoulder.

Comment: watch closer my screenshot, you will notice that I am in the tools tab, while you are in the options tab. For the x mirror to work, try to enable "Multi-Paint" in your brush settings.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I've been doing. I don't have a few of those options you do - Accumulate, Front Faces Only, Falloff, Symmetry etc. - so I don't get it. :-\

Comment: show a fullscreen shot

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7brvLrH

Comment: Oh, shoe. Maybe those tools are only available through blender's daily builds... you can download that here : 
https://builder.blender.org/download/
Be aware, it's less stable than a usual release. Maybe just download the zip version and put that on the side, don't overwrite your stable installation.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll probably just wait for the newest stable release with EVEE. Thing is, a book I've been following uses an old version of Blender - 2.78b - and the author suggests to use X Mirror. Even the names of the bones are set up correctly - Shoulder.L and Shoulder.R.

Comment: Just enable multi-paint for that, i'm sure it's in 2.79

Comment: Yep, did that. Nada. I painted on one side and it doesn't get copied to the other side. I did read a little something though - that if one side isn't symmetrical, it won't do it. I don't know why it wouldn' t be though - I duplicated the right side and mirrored it on the X axis.

Comment: Curious, it works for me. Maybe try enabling topology mirror in the options tab ?

Comment: Aha, that seems to have done it. :D Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, X-Mirror does NOT work retroactively!  You have to have it active *before* doing any weight painting.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that your model is rotated 90 degrees on the Z axis, also the scale is not 1.0 but the skeleton scale is 1.0, which might make it not work properly. It worked perfectly for me after I applied all the transforms (Rotation, Location, Scale), as a plus I did a symmetrize because the model is not perfectly symmetrical and finally I checked for any unwelded vertex.

Hope that helps.